# Bound expected value of product of random variables given information on one

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose that $X,Y$ are positive random variables such that $P(Y \le \tau)\ge 1-\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is small, i.e. $Y$ is bounded with high probability.

Can bounds be constructed for $E[XY]$ that depend on $E[X], \tau,$ and $\epsilon$?

The closest result I have seen is [Theorem 15 of this pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture2.pdf) which is a bound on $E[Y]$. What about for the product?

Can probabilistic statements also be made between $E[XY]$ and X?

Comment: In Theorem 15 of the pdf $X$ is assumed to be non-negative. Your assumption on $Y$ allows $Y$ to be a large negative number with probability $1$ and then if $X = -1$ we don't get any good bound. Do you intend to assume $X,Y \geq 0$?

Comment: I forgot to add that $X,Y$ are positive random variables. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are not assuming independence, integrability, positivity or anything else you can not. The result you linked relies on the fact that the inequality you gave holds for every $\tau$ i.e. $P(Y \leq \tau) \geq 1-f(\tau)$ for some function f.

Comment: Hi @El Duderino, I see. I forgot to add that $X,Y$ are independent. Suppose I make the assumption that $P(Y \le \tau) \ge 1-f (\tau)$. Can anything be deduced?

Comment: With the assumptions of your last comment the whole thing is just that theorem in the linked notes since independence implies that $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{E}[Y]$.

Comment: I am sorry. I wrongly typed the above comment. It should be that $X,Y$ are positive random variables, not independent. Yes, I know the fact that the expectation is just the product of expectation for independent RV's. I'm not looking for that.